# Classic ASP: requesting variables from 'Content-Disposition: form-data'

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating Paypal's Checkout API into a legacy Classic ASP site.

When sending via this front end js:

```
        var postData = {paypal_order_check: 1, order_id: orderData.id};
        fetch('paypal_checkout_validate.asp', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
            body: encodeFormData(postData)
        })
```

This is the payload that is being sent:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZrUIbyscgWBpTxX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paypal_order_check"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZrUIbyscgWBpTxX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="order_id"

3JV215PS364212N
------WebKitFormBoundaryZrUIbyscgWBpTxX--
```

I am trying to 'request' these 2 variables `paypal_order_check` and `order_id` but cant figure out who do to that.
A generic `request` or `request.form` does not work, but using this code (via https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON JSON class):

```
Set UTF8Enc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding") // .NET COMPONENT, required on the server app pool
Set JSON = new JSONobject

lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
request_body = UTF8Enc.GetString(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))

Set request_json = JSON.parse(request_body)
   
Set JSON = nothing
```

--> then I do get the entire payload into the `request_json` variable. But what next?
I thought i could do `paypal_order_check = request("paypal_order_check")`  - bit that is empty too.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to make a request / server roundtrip of your own to put the data and access it server-side.

Comment: Did you successfully received the payload data and put it in a javascript variable? Can you log the received data and see exactly the payload above?

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me in the end. I have ASPupload installed, so the 2nd option listed was easiest to implement. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158652/classic-asp-cannot-get-request-form-values-from-ajax-post-request

Answer (score 0):

If the backend is expecting JSON, don't use `encodeFormData()`. That makes no sense.

Use `JSON.stringify()`