Troubleshooting a "token signature invalid" error, but successful transaction
I recently integrated the newer Paypal Check into my website, using Classic ASP/VBscript. Believe it or not - all works well. I used this site as a guide.
However, periodically, the customer will receive a "token signature invalid" message, but the payment does actually go through.
The customer however thinks it fails, so sometimes will resubmit, landing up as a duplicate payment.
Paypal tech support have unfortunately been very unhelpul to date. They keep asking for screenshots, which (a) is an issue getting from a customer, and (b) there is nothing to see there other than the actual error message, of the invalid token.
I have not been able to find anything useful in the API log.
What should I be looking for? What could cause the seeming error, but with the transaction that is successful?
Added: in Sandbox, the code works for me each time.
JS Code:
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
            "purchase_units": [{
                "custom_id": "<%=x_id%>",
                "description": "Chai Health Insurance #<%=x_id%>",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "<%=configCurr%>",
                    "value": <%=amount%>,
                    "breakdown": {
                        "item_total": {
                            "currency_code": "<%=configCurr%>",
                            "value": <%=amount%>
                        }
                    }
                },
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Chai Health Insurance #<%=x_id%>",
                        "description": "Chai Health Insurance #<%=x_id%>",
                        "unit_amount": {
                            "currency_code": "<%=configCurr%>",
                            "value": <%=amount%>
                        },
                        "quantity": "1",
                        "category": "DIGITAL_GOODS"
                    },
                ]
            }]
        });
    },
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            setProcessing(true);

            var postData = {paypal_order_check: 1, order_id: orderData.id};
            fetch('/paypal_prod/process_wellcome.asp', {
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', // added
                headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
                body: encodeFormData(postData)
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                if(result.status == 1){
                    window.location.href = "thanks.asp?checkout_ref_id="+result.ref_id;
                }else{
                    const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#paymentResponse");
                    messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
                    messageContainer.textContent = result.msg;
                    
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
                        messageContainer.textContent = "";
                    }, 15000);
                }
                setProcessing(false);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');

const encodeFormData = (data) => {
  var form_data = new FormData();

  for ( var key in data ) {
    form_data.append(key, data[key]);
  }
  return form_data;   
}

// Show a loader on payment form processing
const setProcessing = (isProcessing) => {
    if (isProcessing) {
        document.querySelector(".overlay").classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".overlay").classList.add("hidden");
    }
}    
</script>   

Server side process:
// getting vars via ASPupload, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160022/848513    
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.Save
paypal_order_check = Upload.Form("paypal_order_check")
order_id = Upload.Form("order_id")
Set Upload = nothing   
   
   
if paypal_order_check = "" OR order_id = "" then 
   
    Response.LCID = 2057
    set JSON = New JSONobject
    JSON.Add "status",  "0"
    JSON.Add "msg",  "Incomplete vars"
    JSON.Write() 
    set JSON = nothing
    response.end
else
   
    Response.LCID = 2057
    set JSON = New JSONobject
    JSON.Add "status",  "0"
    JSON.Add "msg",  "Transaction failed"
   
    // get order info:   
    orderInfo =  getOrderAPIinfo(GenerateBearerToken,order_id) 
   
   if instr(lcase(orderInfo), "error") > 0 then
        JSON.Change "status",  "0"
        JSON.Change "msg", "" & orderInfo & ""
        JSON.Write() 
        set JSON = nothing
        response.end
    end if 
   

   Set oJSON = New aspJSON
    oJSON.loadJSON(orderInfo)

    order_status = oJSON.data.item("status")
    paypal_id = oJSON.data.item("id")

    For Each key In oJSON.data("purchase_units")
       Set this = oJSON.data("purchase_units").item(key)
       order_custom_id =  this.item("custom_id") 
    Next
    Set oJSON = nothing    
   
    //update database
    // send email
    //send success message

    Response.LCID = 2057
    set JSON = New JSONobject
    JSON.Change "status",  "1"
    JSON.Change "msg",  "Transaction completed!"
    JSON.Add "ref_id",  guid
    JSON.Write() 
    set JSON = nothing
    response.end 
   
    
end if     
         
JSON.Write() 
set JSON = nothing

     
       
function GenerateBearerToken
   
    Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    call objHTTP.open("POST", configPaypalAuthAPI, false)
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en_US")
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(configClientID & ":" & configClientSecret)) 
    call objHTTP.send("grant_type=client_credentials")
    ResponseText = objHTTP.responsetext
    Set objHTTP = nothing 
   
    if instr(ResponseText, "error") then
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON
        oJSON.loadJSON(ResponseText)

        error = oJSON.data.item("error")
        error_description = oJSON.data.item("error_description")
        Set oJSON = nothing    

        GenerateBearerToken = "Error: " & error & " : " & error_description
    else
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON
        oJSON.loadJSON(ResponseText)

        GenerateBearerToken = oJSON.data.item("access_token")
        Set oJSON = nothing    
    end if 
       
end function   
    
    
function getOrderAPIinfo(AuthToken,OrderID)
    
    Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    call objHTTP.open("GET", configPaypalAPI & "/orders/" & OrderID , false)
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en_US")
    call objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & AuthToken) 
    call objHTTP.send()
    ResponseText = objHTTP.responsetext
    Set objHTTP = nothing 
    
    if instr(ResponseText, "error") then
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON
        oJSON.loadJSON(ResponseText)

        error = oJSON.data.item("error")
        error_description = oJSON.data.item("error_description")
        Set oJSON = nothing    

        getOrderAPIinfo = "Error: " & error & " : " & error_description
    else
        getOrderAPIinfo = ResponseText
    end if 
    
    
end function     
    
    

